# how to call an intent from a different class

Tags: android, android-intent, android-handler

I am trying to call an intent from a handler and I don't know how to do it. I have tried many different ways but it does't seem to be working. I want to start the `PrimeNumbersActivity` when the progress dialog reaches its max.

```
public class MyHandler extends Handler {
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    Context context;

    public MyHandler(ProgressDialog progressDialog) {
        this.progressDialog = progressDialog;
    }

    public MyHandler(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        findPrimeNumber(Integer.parseInt(msg.obj.toString()));
    }

    public void findPrimeNumber(int number){

        ArrayList<Integer> primeNumbers = new ArrayList<>();
        boolean isPrimeNumber;
        PrimeNumbers primeNumbers1 = new PrimeNumbers();




        for(int i = 2; i <= number; i++){
            isPrimeNumber = true;
            for(int j = 1; j <= i; j++){
                try {
                    sleep(50);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if(j != 1 && j != i){
                    if(i%j == 0){
                        isPrimeNumber = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            if(isPrimeNumber){
                primeNumbers.add(i);
                primeNumbers1.primeNumbers.add(i);
            }
            progressDialog.setProgress(i*100/number);
            if(progressDialog.getProgress() == progressDialog.getMax()){
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                Intent intent = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(),PrimeNumbersActivity.class);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        }

        for (int i :
                primeNumbers) {
            Log.d(TAG, i + "");
        }
    }
}
```

the PrimeNumbersActivity

```
public class PrimeNumbersActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private PrimeNumbers primeNumbers = new PrimeNumbers();
    private ListView listView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_prime_numbers);

        listView = findViewById(R.id.listView);

        if(primeNumbers.primeNumbers.isEmpty()){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Pas de nombres premiers",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
            ArrayAdapter<Integer> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,primeNumbers.primeNumbers);
            listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        }
    }
}
```

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final int number = 20;
    public Button button;
    public EditText editText;
    public ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    public AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        progressDialog.setMax(100);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        progressDialog.setTitle("Finding prime numbers");
        progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);

        final MyThread thread = new MyThread(progressDialog);
        thread.setName("MyThread");
        thread.start();

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.afficherNombrePremier);
        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(editText.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
                    alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                    alertDialog.setTitle("Warning");
                    alertDialog.setMessage("Veuillez saisir un nombre entier dans la zone de texte");
                    alertDialog.show();
                }
                else{
                    progressDialog.show();
                    Message message = Message.obtain();
                    message.obj = editText.getText().toString();
                    thread.mHandler.sendMessage(message);
                }

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Error:

```
04-24 00:45:15.457 4625-4712/com.example.mohammed.tdservicesex1 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: MyThread
                                                                              Process: com.example.mohammed.tdservicesex1, PID: 4625
                                                                              java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference
                                                                                  at com.example.mohammed.tdservicesex1.MyHandler.findPrimeNumber(MyHandler.java:65)
                                                                                  at com.example.mohammed.tdservicesex1.MyHandler.handleMessage(MyHandler.java:31)
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                  at com.example.mohammed.tdservicesex1.MyThread.run(MyThread.java:22)
```

Thread:

```
public class MyThread extends Thread {
    private static final String TAG = MyThread.class.getSimpleName();
    public MyHandler mHandler;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    public MyThread(ProgressDialog progressDialog) {
        this.progressDialog = progressDialog;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Looper.prepare();
        mHandler = new MyHandler(progressDialog);
        Looper.loop();
    }
}
```

Comment: is your code error?

Comment: And what is the problem? Your code looks fine.

Comment: the application seems to be working but when I click the button to execute the handler the app crashes and it gives me an error I'll make sure to attach the error alongst with the classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is happened because you haven't set any context with your constructor in your `MyHandler` class. Your constructors is like the following:

```
public class MyHandler extends Handler {
  ...

  public MyHandler(ProgressDialog progressDialog) {
    this.progressDialog = progressDialog;
  }

  public MyHandler(Context context){
    this.context = context;
  }

  ...
}
```

you can see that you have 2 different constructors. In your code, you're only using the first constructor, you never assign the context with your second constructor. This is a common error when you're using multiple constructor for a class.

To solve the problem, you need to change your constructor so that it needs two parameters: ProgressDialog and Context. Change the constructor to something like this:

```
public class MyHandler extends Handler {
  ...

  public MyHandler(ProgressDialog progressDialog, Context context) {
    this.progressDialog = progressDialog;
    this.context = context;
  }

  ...
}
```

Comment: thank you so much this solution has worked for me. I appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

I believe you cannot start an activity using the application context (in a straightforward manner). You either have to

1. Use activity context
2. Use application context but add this flag `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`

Be warned that `FLAG_ACTIVITYNEW_TASK` will start a new task in the history stack

Try something like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(),PrimeNumbersActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: I have found something about FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK but I don't really know how to use it in my code

Comment: thank you so much. I tried it but it still gives me that error of a null pointer exception. I don't know if I have to initialize the MyHandlerI(Context context) in the main activity

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you declared PrimeNumbersActivity in Android Manifest
2. This should work:

   ```
   Intent intent = new Intent(context,PrimeNumbersActivity.class);
   context.startActivity(intent);
   ```
3. If #2 does not work. It means this condition is always false:

   ```
   if(progressDialog.getProgress() == progressDialog.getMax())
   ```

Comment: the PrimeNumbersActivity is already declared in Android Manifest. The condition is correct, I tried it without calling the intent from the handler it seems to be working